# Eclipse Virgo shutdown for no reason on EC2

Tags: tomcat, ssh, amazon-ec2, osgi, eclipse-virgo

I'm having a problem of a clean install of Eclipse Virgo (3.5) shutting down apparently for no reason once it's started on a Ubuntu image 12.04 on Amazon EC2.
I'm starting Virgo from SSH, startup works fine but after some hours the server stops, the log report the following (see the third line):

```
[2012-12-10 11:57:14.804] INFO  http-bio-8080-exec-9         org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping   Mapped URL path [/splash] onto handler 'splashController' 
[2012-12-10 11:57:14.840] INFO  http-bio-8080-exec-9         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet                 FrameworkServlet 'splash': initialization completed in 92 ms 
[2012-12-10 15:33:27.488] INFO  System Bundle Shutdown       o.e.g.b.extender.internal.activator.ContextLoaderListener         Stopping [org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender] bundle v.[1.0.0.RELEASE] 
[2012-12-10 15:33:27.493] INFO  kernel-dm-10                 o.e.g.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext   Unpublishing application context OSGi service for bundle Virgo Kernel Admin
 Shell (org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.shell) 
[2012-12-10 15:33:27.494] INFO  kernel-dm-10                 o.e.g.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext   Closing OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.she
ll, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml): startup date [Mon Dec 10 11:40:04 UTC 2012]; root of context hierarchy 
[2012-12-10 15:33:27.495] INFO  kernel-dm-10                 o.s.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory              Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultL
istableBeanFactory@1fc7875: defining beans [commandProcessor,singleCommandExecutor,ioManager,completerRegistry,modelAccessorHelper,stateService,installCommand,bundleCommands,serviceCommands,packageComma
nds,configCommands,planCommands,parCommands,shutdownCommand,exitCommand,helpCommand,helpAccessor,helpCommandCompleter,bundleCompleter,packageCompleter,configCompleter,parCompleter,planCompleter,installC
ompleter,longConverter,stringConverter,commandResolver,commandRegistry,commandInvoker,converterRegistry,quasiFrameworkFactory,moduleContextAccessor,eventLogger,configAdmin,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.s
ervice.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#0,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#1,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBe
an#2,userRegionBundleContext,deployer,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#3,regionDigraph,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactor
yBean#4,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#5,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#6,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service
.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#7,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#8,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#9,o
rg.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#10,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#11,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.export
er.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#12,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#13,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#14,org.e
clipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#15,objectNameCreator,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#16,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.
service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#17,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#18,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactor
yBean#19,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#20,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#21,org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.serv
ice.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean#22]; root of factory hierarchy 
[2012-12-10 15:33:27.497] INFO  kernel-dm-10                 o.e.g.blueprint.service.exporter.support.OsgiServiceFactoryBean   Unregistered service [ServiceRegistrationWrapper for {org.eclipse.virgo.ker
nel.shell.CommandCompleter}={org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.shell.completer.commmandNames=install, org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.bean.name=installCompleter, org.springframework.osgi.bean.name=installCompleter,
 osgi.service.blueprint.compname=installCompleter, Bundle-SymbolicName=org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.shell, Bundle-Version=3.5.0.RELEASE, service.id=216}]
```

**These are the server properties**

- Java VM Description: Oracle Corporation(OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM) 23.2-b09
- Java Version: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_09
- Operating System: Linux(amd64) 3.2.0-31-virtual Server
- Time Zone:   Etc/UTC Virgo
- Server Version:  3.5.0.RELEASE

Any idea or suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: You don't happen to have a application bundle runnin in it that does call a System.exit() ?

Comment: There is a related [thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/441398/992902/) on the Virgo community forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tarelli cross-posted this on the Virgo community forum, and the [cause was found](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/441398/992902/#msg_992902)

The problem was when his SSH connection closed after being idle for long enough, the Virgo process started from SSH also closed.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to link it.